# Update Manager is not appearing in main dash.

Tags: updates, update-manager, permissions

I am currently a user of Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell N4030, however my update manager is not appearing in dash home. I would like to update it to 12.04, but whenever I am trying with other alternate technique I receive an error such as below:

```
vpsingh@vpsingh-Inspiron-N4030:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Very normal operation, I have no idea what the problem is.
Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not coming dash home", Is it that ur not able to see the icon when u search by typing in "Update Manager" ??

Comment: Are u trying to do simultaneous installations, One using the Software Center and Updating using the terminal ??

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` , you need to use `sudo` before apt-get command . And by `coming` do you mean  it doesn't show up or not present in Application menu. Do you want to Upgrade then do refer this [upgrade help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command `apt-get` using `sudo` or using root privilege. For example, `sudo apt-get update`.

You say, you want to upgrade to the next release i.e Precise. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Update the package database

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install `update-manager-core`

   ```
    sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
   ```
3. Use this command to upgrade

   ```
    do-release-upgrade
   ```

Then follow the on-screen instruction.

For more help, check this page

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/

You are now upgraded to Precise

Answer (score 0):

I would try using, to update package manager, this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The command is set into root user when using the command:

```
sudo
```

You are awarded root permissions. 
When using this command you will be asked to enter your password as the example below shows.

```
example@exampledesk:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for example:
```

When you enter your password, the characters are not shown to ensure what you are typing is secure, just be reassured that what you are typing is in fact being recorded. It will appear as so:

```
[sudo] password for example:
```

However your password will be entered and you can simply press enter and you should see the updater receiving the packages.

Now as you said you wanted to upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10, you can use the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

This is for if the update-manager-core is not yet installed. I reccomend this if it is not showing up in your dash.

Then:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

This launches the upgrade tool.

The terminal will ask you for your password again as it did in the first example.
Simply type it an press enter, you should be able to upgrade.

Now you can couple the two commands and enter them at the same time only typing the password once if you do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install update-manager-core && do-release-upgrade
```

Again this time you will be asked for you password and both processes should be completed. 
I hope this was of help to you!

Comment: does `sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrade distribution upgrade? I don't think, so. Please check this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/